# How to write Spark Dataframe/Dataset to multiple outputs?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

I would like to transform a `Dataset[T]` into multiple datasets `Dataset[U1]`, `Dataset[U2]`, ..., `Dataset[Un]`, where `U1` to `Un` are different types. Moreover, I would like to write them in parallel. I know how to do this with pair RDDs and I am not looking into partitioning (which means `U1` = ... = `Un`). How to do it?

Comment: May I ask what your use case is? It doesn't seem very performant to divide this into different datasets

Comment: It's not clear to me what's the issue there. What did you try so far and why you're not satisfied with it?

Comment: Here's what's possible to do with an RDD: https://gist.github.com/mlehman/df9546f6be2e362bbad2. I just need an RDD of pairs of strings, where a key is a location to where to write the value.

Answer (score 0):

I found something called `foreachBatch` when using Structured Streaming:

```scala
streamingDF.writeStream.foreachBatch { (batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
  batchDF.persist()
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 1
  batchDF.write.format(...).save(...)  // location 2
  batchDF.unpersist()
}
```

More details [here](https://docs.databricks.com/structured-streaming/foreach.html).